# How do you set the proper number of threads when executing concurrency task on iOS device?

Tags: c++, ios, multithreading, concurrency

I developed a cross-platform c++ library which spawn threads at runtime.
I used a concurrency queue to dispatch computing tasks, thus every thread will be busy at most of the time.

Now the question is how to get a proper number of threads at runtime. As my task has no I/O or networking operation but calculations and heap-memory allocations, the best strategy would be spawn thread per CPU core:

My code looks like below:

```
#include "concurrentqueue.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex io_m;

struct Task {
    int n;
};

void some_time_consuming_operations(Task &t) {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < t.n; ++i)
        vec.push_back(1);
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(io_m);
        std::cout << "thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " done, vec size:" << vec.size() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    // moodycamel's lockfree queue: https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue
    moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue<Task> tasks;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        tasks.enqueue(Task{(i % 5) * 1000000 + 1000000});

    // I left 2 threads for ui and other usages
    std::vector<std::thread> jobs(std::max((size_t)2, (size_t)std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 2));

    std::cout << "thread num:" << jobs.size() << std::endl;

    for (auto &job : jobs) {
        job = std::thread([&tasks]() {
            Task task;
            while (tasks.try_dequeue(task))
                some_time_consuming_operations(task);
        });
    }

    for (auto &job : jobs)
        job.join();

    return 0;
}
```

However, when enabling multi-threading on my iOS device(iPhone XR, A12), the test program is 2-times slower than the single thread mode. I 've test it on My windows machine with a 4-core 8-thread intel CPU, and it is 6-times faster than the single thread mode.

On my iPhone, the `hardware_concurrency` function returns `6`, which is the exactly core number of Apple A12. On my windows machine, the number is 8.

I understand there are 4 energy-efficient cores called Tempest lies i Apple's A12, but since they [claimed](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2017/09/the-future-is-here-iphone-x/) that A11/A12 will use all six cores simultaneously (I kept the charge on during test). I have no idea why its slower than the single thread mode.

The test program is a game app build by UE4.

Comment: Without code, it's impossible to tell. Since the performance is affected by hardware, you can have it configurable by the user - or benchmark from *your* app at run time and pick the best solution.

Comment: I've added some code.@MichaelChourdakis

Comment: @Scheff sorry for some reason  I can't put my real code here, but i've correct some mistakes, please see my update. I create a vector of threads with size of `std::max(2, std::hardware_concurrency() - 2)`

Comment: _I can't put my real code here_ One reason is that it's not well liked in SO. Instead, reproduce your issue in a [mcve]. If this didn't help to even find the mistake by yourself then you have something to post in your question. You could use an online compiler for this (as I did above).

Comment: Shouldn't there be a loop in the thread lambda? And a `return` if `tasks` became empty?

Comment: I 've created a minmal case that compiled and executed successfully as  expected, but it requires a single head for the cuncurrency queue. @Scheff Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The four slower cores are *a lot* slower than the fast cores. So if you took a task that takes 6 seconds on a fast core, and ran one second worth of work on each core, then the two fast cores would finish after a second, while the four slow cores would take maybe ten seconds.

If you use GCD, iOS will shuffle these six threads between the cores, so you can gain up to a factor 2.4 in speed. If your thread implementation doesn't do this, then you are slowing down things.

The solutions: Either use GCD (and get a speedup of 2.4) or use only two threads (and get a speedup of 2.0). That's on an iPhone XR; you'd need to find out the number of fast cores somehow.

Comment: Since I'm developing a cross platform lib in C++, there seems no way to use GCD. Also I'afraid it's actually the same as a concurrency queue as I used in C++.